# How to display nested component with react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my application, I have several routes defined with react router dom. 
All the routes works fine but the nested routes are not displaying instead it taking to the error page.

> Here is my index routes

```
const initialRoutes = [
{
 path: "/",
 component: Home
},
{
 path: "/login",
 component: Login
},
{
 path: "/dashboard",
 component: Dashboardlayout
},
{
 path: "*",
 component: Error
} /* And so on. */
];
export default initialRoutes;
```

Here the Dashboardlayout consists of other dashboard related routes

> Dashboardlayout page

```
import Dashboard from "../pages/DashboardPages/Dashboard";
import Create from "../pages/DashboardPages/Create";

var dashRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-bank",
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard/create",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-bank",
    component: Create
  }
];
export default dashRoutes;
```

> And my App.js page is, which maps though the initialRoutes file.

```
render() {
    const routeComponents = RootRoutes.map(({ path, component }, key) => (
      <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />
    ));
    return (
      <div className="main-body">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>{routeComponents}</Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        {this.state.menuModal ? (
          <MenuToggle toggleMenuModal={() => this.toggleMenuModal()} />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The problem is when the url is localhost:3000/dashbaord its displaying the Dashboard component but when the url is localhost:3000/dashboard/create its redirecting me to the Not found/Error page. Why it's happening ?

Answer (score 0):

[`exact` prop](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool) prevents `/dashboard` route from being matched at `/dashboard/create` path.

For parent routes that have nested routes there should be no `exact`.

Comment: if there is no exact then its displaying the Home component always for any path.

Comment: Don't use `exact` on routes that expect to have nested routes like `/dashboard` . I suppose this means that route definitions need to be changed in some way.