# why react route is not working properly with exact property?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React routes are not working with exact property .But when i remove exact proprty and put second route as path="/Admin" as first route object then its works fine as

```
{ path: "/Admin", name: "Home", component: Dashboard},
..., 
{ path: "/", name: "Frontend", component: Frontend }
```

Please see whole code below and suggest me what i am missing.

Dashboard Routes file (File in which i define routed of dashboard)

```
import Dashboard from "views/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import UserProfile from "views/UserProfile/UserProfile";

const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/Admin/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "pe-7s-graph",
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: "/Admin/user",
    name: "User Profile",
    icon: "pe-7s-user",
    component: UserProfile
  },

  { redirect: true, path: "/Admin", to: "/Admin/dashboard", name: "Dashboard" }
];

export default dashboardRoutes;
```

Dashboard.jsx (File in which i define admin layout and make path for routes)

```
...
import dashboardRoutes from "routes/dashboard.jsx";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
          <Switch>
            {dashboardRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
                console.log('prop.name', prop.name);
              if (prop.name === "Notifications") {
                return (
                  <Route path={prop.path} key={key}
                    render={routeProps => (
                      <prop.component
                        {...routeProps}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                );
              }
              if (prop.redirect){
                return <Redirect from={prop.path} to={prop.to} key={key} />;
              }
              return (
                <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />
              );
            })}
          </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Index routes file (I define index routes for admin and front end)

```
import Dashboard    from "pathTo/Dashboard.jsx";
import Frontend     from "pathTo/Frontend.jsx";
import AdminLogin   from "pathTo/AdminAuth.jsx";

var indexRoutes = [
    { path: "/", name: "Frontend", component: Frontend },
    { path: "/Admin", name: "Home", component: Dashboard},
    { path: "/Admin-login", name: "AdminLogin", component: AdminLogin}
];

export default indexRoutes;
```

Index file (File in which i define store and index routes)

```
import { history } from './helper/history';
import store from "./redux/store/index";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";
...
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} >
        <Switch>
          {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
            return <Route  path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
          })}
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: This is exactly same case as https://stackoverflow.com/a/53268448/3731501 . You don't need `exact` on routes that contain nested routes like `/Admin`

Comment: Even the switch example in the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) show this...